# What happened to my Chiphacker reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It was in excess of 900 when Chiphacker was still Chiphacker; now it's only 808.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the migration to SE 2.0 reputation was recalculated to match the rest of our sites.  See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/ for details.

You can also view the new point system here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: and what abou the badges?

Comment: Badges remain unchanged.